# How to create a python program that take text from the keyboard and send it to an Arduino

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to control arduino using Python. So, i wonder how can I create a python program that takes a string variable(a word that I will type in python serial) and send it to arduino serial port.

im getting this error

```
Enter Message:Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "C:\Users\JohnC\Desktop\trial.py", line 69, in serialThread
s.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("ArduinoComPortNumber",9600,timeout=1)
for message in iter(lambda:raw_input("Enter Message:"),""):
    msg_with_newline = message+"\n"
    print "You Say:",repr(msg_with_newline)
    ser.write(msg_with_newline)
    print "Arduino Says:",repr(ser.read(10000))
```

I made it more readable :P

you could do the actual serial comm in the thread this would allow you to see output while you were getting ready to type...

```
pending_send_messages = []


def serialThread(comPort):
    try:
        s = serial.Serial(comPort,9600,timeout=0.5)
        while True:
            print "Arduino Says:",repr(s.read(1000))
            if pending_send_messages:
               print "You Say:",pending_send_messages[0]
               if not pending_send_messages[0]:break;
               s.write(pending_send_messages.pop(0)+"\n")
    finally:
        s.close()    


import threading

t = threading.Thread(target=serialThread,args=("COM11",)) #make sure to use appropriate com port
t.start()
for message in iter(lambda:raw_input("Enter Message:"),""):
    pending_send_messages.append(message)

pending_send_messages.append(0)
```

Comment: how can i write this?, if msg_with_newline == "info"

Comment: how can I make it read line from different port and accepts input command at the same time?

Comment: what im trying to do is read the serial port of arduino all the time; but at the same time, it reads input command like what you have above... cause it seems like if starts to read the serial port of arduino, it stops listening to input command, or vice versa.

Comment: you cannot read while you write ... you can write and then you can read (like i do in the example)

Comment: is there a code that make you stop from writing until it finished executing a function?.

Comment: sure ... all functions are blocking so just call the function before the raw_input ... you will not execute the raw input until the methods and instructions before it complete ...